# If $(X_t)$ is sample-continuous, when is $E[Y|\mathcal F_t^X]$ sample-continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_t)$ be a sample-continuous stochastic process on $[0,1]$, $(\mathcal F_t^X)$ its natural filtration, and $Y$ an integrable random variable. When is $E[Y|\mathcal F_t^X]$ sample-continuous?

I feel that there is at least 2 scenarios where we have sample-continuity:

1. $X_t=Y$
2. The sigma algebra of $Y$ is not in $\mathcal F_t^X$ for all $t \in [0,1)$

The first scenario is trivial, the second is based on intuition: if the sigma algebra of $Y$ is not in $\mathcal F_t^X$ for all $t \in [0,1)$, the conditional expectation cannot "snap" to value $Y$. But I do not have a proof.

Comment: Consider $X_t = t Z,$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, your probability space being $(\mathbf{R}, \mathscr{B}, \mu),$ the real line with Borel sets and $\mu$ is the standard normal distribution (i.e. $Z$ is the identity function). Then $\mathscr{F}_0^X$ is trivial  while all other $\mathscr{F}_t^X$ will coincide with $\mathscr{B};$ if $Y$ is $\mathscr{B}$-measurable (i.e. a random variable), then $E(Y \mid \mathscr{F}_t^X) = E(Y)$ when $t = 0$ and it will be equal to $Y$ for $t > 0.$

Comment: Is continuous up to modification okay for sample-continuity?  I.e. if you had conditions such that there was a sample-continuous process $Z_t$ such that $Z_t = E[Y|\mathcal F_t^X]$ a.s. for every $t$, would that be a sufficient answer?

Comment: @user6247850 I guess so since conditional expectation is only defined almost surely.